# Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run?

Tags: android, android-studio

```
I recently upgraded to Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1 Patch 1.  
When trying to build a legacy project, I get the error 
 

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
      Your current JDK is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre
      You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.  

I installed jdk-20 and updated JAVA_HOME and JAVA_PATH as follows    
    JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\JDK-20  
    JAVA_PATH: C:\Program Files\Java\JDK-20\bin\java.exe
```

I can't understand where the `jdk1.8.0_251\jre` is coming from.
**Can anybody educate me?**

Answer (score 1):

Oh I've been having the same problem every time I launch a new project on AS for a while now, I honestly have no idea why it defaults to jdk1.8.0, but I will provide a solution to the error you are getting:

go to: File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, deployment -> Build tools -> gradle

and change the gradle version from 1.8 to 11
[image]