# 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' error with Android Studio Flamingo

Tags: java, android-studio, compiler-errors, radiance-flamingo

When I updated Android Studio to Flamingo version, Gradle suggested the upgrade and I upgraded with AGP from 7.4 to 8.0. I was never able to debug after this upgrade, and as a result of my research, I could not come to a conclusion. If there is any information I have given missing for the problem, if you specify, I can make additions. I'm sharing my gradle module app codes because I think the problem stems from here.

My build.gradle(app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    compileSdkVersion 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.packagename"
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 15
        versionName "1.4"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
    }
    namespace 'com.example.packagename'

}
```

Error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> superclass access check failed: class butterknife.compiler.ButterKnifeProcessor$RScanner (in unnamed module @0x1db9193f) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.tree to unnamed module @0x1db9193f
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:149)
.
.
.
```

I tried almost all the suggestions mentioned in StackOverFlow for solution but couldn't reach a solution.

Comment: check my answer it is working for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/76070809/12936324

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm getting this error:
Minimum supported Gradle version is 7.5. Current version is 7.2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android AGP 8 + Gradle 8 + Kotlin 1.8 causes error in Kapt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76030538/android-agp-8-gradle-8-kotlin-1-8-causes-error-in-kapt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by reverting to the old version as follows.
First of all, I downloaded and installed the Electric Eel version. (Official archive site to download old versions: [**CLICK**](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive))

I then changed the content of **gradle-wrapper.properties** to:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0.1-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

Then I set the **Gradle JDK** with the steps "**File > Build, Execution, Deploymend > Gradle**" as follows: **jbr-11** *(Jetbrains Runtime version 11.0.5...)*

I then followed these steps: "**File > Project Structure**"
And
Android Gradle Plugin Version: **7.4.2**
Gradle Version: **8.0.1**

Right now at least I'm able to compile and run my project.
Thanks to everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 4):

For now the only way how to get your project buildable is to make sure to use Java 11.

1. In Android Studio go to `Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle`
2. `Gradle JDK` - make sure you have selected Java 11
3. In case it did not help, do not change the setting, rather try "Invalidate Caches..." with option to restart Android Studio and see if that helps.

Also I would suggest to downgrade AGP back to 7.4. I know that this does not bring all the features and fixes on board, but as you said, there are few info out there about what we can do, now.
On the other hand, author of Butterknife [claims](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife) that he will manage "critical bug fixes for integration with AGP":
[image]

Also make sure that you have configure your `build.gradle` file to use Java 11:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = "11"
    targetCompatibility = "11"
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer.

Gradle JDK:11, I'm sure of it.

For AGP:
Yesterday I saw that it says we need to use Embedded JDK on its official site and I tried it but it didn't work.
As you said, I downgraded to the previous version as plugin:7.4.2, library:7.5.1, but no solution.

There's also this error:
Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: Cannot add a configuration with name 'androidJdkImage' as a configuration with that name already exists.